# Drawing a prism with CoreAnimation

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, core-animation

I'm trying to draw a prism and animate it with CoreAnimation. But I can't find a good solution to draw the fan of rainbow colors.

[image: prism]

There a a couple of ways to do that, each of them has disadvantages:

- I could simply use an image. But I allow the user to zoom into the scene and I'd like to avoid any artefacts.
- Using a `CAGradientLayer` produces a nice rainbow. Unfortunately there is now skew (or squeeze) transformation available to transform the rectangular rainbow into a triangle.
- A simple skew effect of the layer can be obtained by modifying the m34 matrix element of the layer's transform matrix. But I wasn't able to obtain a triangle shape (because the layer would have to be of infinite size).
- OpenGL. That'll work, but maybe there's a simpler way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve any kind of quadrilateral by modifying `transform` property of `CALayer`. [AGGeometryKit](https://github.com/hfossli/AGGeometryKit) has some nice tools to make `CATransform3D` for a quad.